# Slim with symfony validation

Tags: php, symfony, slim, symfony-validator

I use slim and want ro implement symfony validation way. For this I install `symfony/validator doctrine/annotations` and after that create class with assert annotaion, but after validate I did not have any violation. When I try use `addMethodMapping` with custom function, where I added `addPropertyConstraint` to `metadata`, I had violation, everythiung work
my class

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Company
{
/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\Length(
 *      min = 5,
 *      max = 50
 * )
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $company_country;

/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $company_org_nr;
```

and validate logic, where `comapnyObj` object with empty properties

```
$validator = Validation::createValidator();
$constraintViolationList = $validator->validate($comapnyObj);
```

and had error `[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length" in property CDB\Collection\Company::$name does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.`

how to correct use annotation for symfony validation ?

Answer (score 0):

I found just I did not carefully read the documentation

```
/** @var ClassLoader $loader */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader([$loader, 'loadClass']);
```